# pass over an ID from a PHP Update page with header

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the ID of a user from the edit profile page to a page that stats if it was successful or not.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php
     // Connect to server and select database.
     include("connect.php");

     // update data in mysql database 
     $sql="UPDATE apply SET     email='$_POST[email]'                   

     WHERE authentication='$_POST[authentication]'" or die ("cant find player");

     $result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("this stuffedup");

     // if successfully updated. 
     if($result){
        header('location: ../updated_profile.php?authentication=$row['authentication']');
     }else{
         echo "Something has went wrong";
     }
?>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: header("location: ../updated_profile.php?authentication=" . $row['authentication']);

Comment: Is there a reason you're opening and closing PHP tags so many times?

Comment: Thank you but i think my problem is else where becouse its not showing the id number when i hover over the links.

Comment: Not really - i was working on small parts at a time on a test page and just copied and pasted full thing over.

Answer (score 1):

Break out your quotes:

```
header('location: ../updated_profile.php?authentication='.$row['authentication']);
```

Also, update your query string as follows:

```
$sql="UPDATE apply SET email = '".$_POST[email]."' WHERE authentication='".$_POST[authentication]."'";
```

Finally, please read up on SQL injection, and how to prevent it.

Comment: Ok done what everyone has suggested and its still not passing over the id.

Comment: Where do you obtain the `$row` variable from? Where do you actually fetch the data from your query?

Comment: thank you BenM - didnt notice i had taken the lines to collect infomation from database and put them in the $row